# Am I allowed to add some legal information into my answers?

Tags: discussion, legal, terms-of-service

I am posting an answer that contains code to use hardware to control a thermostat in a house with the code. However, since there are still bugs, I want to add a little snippet of legal code. Here is what I have written:

> **THE ABOVE CODE IS PROVIDED AS IS WITHOUT ANY WARRANTIES. I AM NOT RESPONSIBLE FOR ANY DAMAGE, WHETHER INTELLECTUAL OR PROPRIETARY, DUE TO CODE OR HARDWARE FAILURE.**
>
> [Note to Moderators and editors: Please do not modify or remove the statement above to protect me and any editors of this code if it were to malfunction due to modification or improper use.]

---

Are we allowed to post snippets like that in our answers to protect ourselves, or does the existing [terms and conditions](https://stackexchange.com/legal) of SE already protect the user? I know it prevents someone from just browsing the web suing SE, but does it protect the user who wrote that? If not, would that be considered spam and removed?

Comment: Nope. All code is under the cc-wiki +attribution license.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII You completely missed the point. The OP is trying to avoid being sued for burning someone's house down. He doesn't care about the license.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The existing terms and conditions already covers, as stated in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18571/213634) answer.

The linked answer is slightly outdated, hence:

> 9 Limitation of liability
>
> In no event shall Stack Exchange, its directors, officers, shareholders, employees or
> members be liable with respect to the Network or the Services for (a) any indirect,
> incidental, punitive, or consequential damages of any kind whatsoever; (b) damages for
> loss of use, profits, data, images, Subscriber Content or other intangibles; (c)
> damages for unauthorized use, non-performance of the Network, errors or omissions; or
> (d) damages related to downloading or posting Content. Stack Exchange's and the
> Network's collective liability under this agreement shall be limited to three hundred
> United States Dollars. Some states do not allow the exclusion or limitation of
> incidental or consequential damages, so the above limitations and exclusions may not
> apply to Subscriber.

**NOTE/EDIT**: I think there is an inconsistency in the ToS. In the quote I provide above, `members` are mentioned. However, as one reads the ToS, that is the first and only reference to `members`. Previously, the reader/user is mentioned as `(“Subscriber” or “You”)` . I *think* that they intend to include `members` in this definition, but I cannot know for sure.

All that said, I think I would find another site if I had to read legal disclaimers every single time I came looking for an answer.